# Newbie Question: PDO and MYSQL INSERT Query problem

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm attempting to be more secure and start using PDO and prepared statements. This had been recommended to me and I've read up on these two websites:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/
and
http://webdevrefinery.com/forums/topic/1272-your-mysql-code-sucks

I've hit a brick wall and I can't understand why the following doesn't work. I am trying to insert a row (to log a 404 error). I have read up about named and unnamed placeholders and I think the named placeholder method will be easier to maintain. I've also tried using "try" and "catch" for the first time. All of this is completely new to me, so please be kind! I don't get any errors but the code doesn't update the database- I get zero rows returned.

Here is the code:

```
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$domainName = "http://domain.com";
$_dtNow = date("d-m-Y H:i:s");
$_referer = $domainName.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$_thisPage = $domainName.$url;
$_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$_host = $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'];
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {$_ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];} else {$_ua = "unset";}

$host =     'localhost';
$port =     3306; // This is the default port for MySQL
$database = 'databaseName';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
  // Construct the DSN, or "Data Source Name".  Really, it's just a fancy name
  // for a string that says what type of server we're connecting to, and how
  // to connect to it.  As long as the above is filled out, this line is all
  // you need :)
  $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$database";

try {
  // Connect!
  $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);  
  $data = array( 
                'dateTime' =>   $_dtNow, 
                'referer' =>    $_referer, 
                'page' =>       $_thisPage,
                'ip' =>         $_ip,
                'host' =>       $_host,
                'ua' =>         $_ua
                );  
  $statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO 404s (dateTime, referer, page, ip, host, ua) value (:dateTime, :referer, :page, :ip, :host, :ua)");
  $statement->execute($data);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage();  
}  



?>
```

Comment: Your code *seems* okay. But while testing remove the try/catch wrapping. And to get any you also need to add `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` after connecting. Curiosly PDO is silent per default.

Comment: @mario - Aha- thanks for this. I hadn't realised errors were silent. The problem was that the $_host variable was null and it didn't like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure of the table  name is `404s` it sound like an incorrect identifier.

```
 INSERT INTO 404s (dateTime, referer, page, ip, host, ua) value (:dateTime, :referer, :page, :ip, :host, :ua)
```

Try :

```
 INSERT INTO `404s` (dateTime, referer, page, ip, host, ua) value (:dateTime, :referer, :page, :ip, :host, :ua)
```

Use backquote around *`404s`*

**Note**
Keep in mind that construct such as :

```
create table `404` ( `33` integer);
```

Are valid .

When you build complex request use of ` is very useful to avoid some kind of painful SQL errors especially when you format request from an introspection algorithm.

Like table, columns and database have to be protected.

Comment: Was wondering that too. To my surprise Mysql accepts such silly table names without backticks. (Certainly not standard SQL compliant anyway..)

Comment: @mario I can't seem to write the backquotes in this comment, but anyway I have tried doing this and it hasn't made any difference.

Comment: @VGE - what do you mean by columns name?

Comment: Mario, my level of mysql does not accept request without backticks for identifier like 404s.

Comment: @VGE: It certainly depends on the mysql version. I tried `5.1.49` and it worked. But if yours runs in `--ansi` compliant mode, it probably wouldn't. So using backticks is certainly valid advise.

Comment: I resolved the problem by adding $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);command which gave me the exact error. This was due to the $_host variable being null. It wasn't anything to do with the lack of backticks, which I had included anyway but Stackoverflow didn't include.

Comment: I use ANSI and TRADITIONAL modes on my mysql connections, and because of that most of my sql can be transfered as is to other databases. Not silly backticks needed.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Dave Kiss, the SQL statement has a small typo at 'value'. It should be 'VALUES'.

```
INSERT INTO 404s (dateTime, referer, page, ip, host, ua) VALUES (:dateTime, :referer, :page, :ip, :host, :ua)
```

Maybe that is all.

BTW: Using leading numbers in identifiers (like your table name 404s) is bad style. You may use them, but you have to but the table name in backticks:

```
INSERT INTO `404s` (dateTime, referer, page, ip, host, ua) VALUES (:dateTime, :referer, :page, :ip, :host, :ua)
```

Resources:

1. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html
2. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifiers.html

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the colons to your keys in the data array.

```
/* Execute a prepared statement by passing an array of insert values */

  $data = array( 
                ':dateTime' =>   $_dtNow, 
                ':referer' =>    $_referer, 
                ':page' =>       $_thisPage,
                ':ip' =>         $_ip,
                ':host' =>       $_host,
                ':ua' =>         $_ua
                );  
  $statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO 404s (dateTime, referer, page, ip, host, ua) value (:dateTime, :referer, :page, :ip, :host, :ua)");
  $statement->execute($data);
```

Comment: Are you supposed to add colons to the data array? I hadn't seen that in the examples in the articles I read. In any case this hasn't worked.